# Xcode: How do I reset the state of all Buttons from the main view controller using a class

Tags: xcode, swift4

I have a class for my buttons that changes the colour when pressed, alternating between on and off.

```
class KSPickButton: UIButton {

    var isOn = true

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initButton()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initButton()

    }

    func initButton() {
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        layer.borderColor = Colors.shanklinGreen.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2
        backgroundColor = .clear
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(KSPickButton.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        activateButton(bool: !isOn)
    }

    func activateButton(bool: Bool) {

        isOn = bool

        let color = bool ? .clear : Colors.shanklinGreen
        //let title = bool ? "" : ""
        let titleColor = bool ?  .white: Colors.shanklinBlack

        //setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(titleColor, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. I have 20 buttons on my main view controller and they flip between on and off as expected... Then maybe after pressing 6, I want to reset them all to off. I have a reset button on my main view controller, but I cannot work out how I can reset them all?

I can make them all look reset but the bool remains as was...

How do I call this class for all buttons and reset them correctly?

Comment: For more clarity, please include code of adding buttons to VC and the reset button action code

Comment: Currently the buttons are manually placed, and I have no reset code yet. I am thinking maybe I should add there buttons using code, then recall this code when I reset.. will look at that option. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduced an observer with 'isOn' variable. You can try using following code snippet in 'KSPickButton' class. After that you need to take all subviews from view controllers (where buttons are placed) and set 'isOn' to 'false' for all of them.

```
class KSPickButton: UIButton {

public var isOn:Bool = true {
didSet {
  handleButtonStateChange()
 }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initButton()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initButton()

}

func initButton() {
    layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    layer.borderColor = Colors.shanklinGreen.cgColor
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2
    backgroundColor = .clear
    setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    addTarget(self, action: #selector(KSPickButton.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func buttonPressed() {
    isOn = !isOn
}

func handleButtonStateChange() {
    let color = isOn ? .clear : Colors.shanklinGreen
    let titleColor = isOn ?  .white: Colors.shanklinBlack
    setTitleColor(titleColor, for: .normal)
    backgroundColor = color
}
}
```

Here is code snippet you need to implement in your view controller as explained above.

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
------
------

for subview in view.subviews where subview.isKind(of: KSPickButton.self)&&(subview as? KSPickButton)?.isOn == true {
  (subview as? KSPickButton)?.isOn = false
 }

-----
-----
}
```